# Can we write a Insert query Lookup Activity in ADF

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

At the end of the pipeline I wanted to write the below query
INSERT INTO [TestTable] (Job_name, status) VALUES (Job_name, current_timestamp()).

Jobname will be passed as a parameter.

Can this be written in Lookup, please let me know.

Comment: It is technically possible to do this in Lookups (as long you provide a dummy output) why not use a Stored Procedure activity?  The Lookups approach is a bit of a hack and makes the pipeline less self-documenting, ie you are using a Lookup activity to do something it's not really meant for.

Comment: I also think this type of logging is a bit of an anti-pattern in ADF.  Pipelines have loads of logging built in which can  viewed via the portal, can be queried in Log Analytics or the REST API.  Bolting on individual tasks via Lookups or Stored Procs leads to bloat in your pipelines and you’re not even getting a full logging experience.

Comment: Thanks for reply, iam using below SQL
insert into Table1 (Column1) values (pipeline().parameters.job_name);
select x;

insert into Table1 (Column1) values (activity('CONTROL_ENTRY').output,firstRow.JOB_NAME;
select x;

Is this correct, both are giving '.' error, any help please

Answer (score 1):

Definitely possible, but should you write massive inserts/scripts within a lookup... probably not a great idea, but see below (Truncate Example, but will work the same with an insert)

[image: LOOKUP EXAMPLE]

I use this method for small things like truncating a table, but never with big code that should be stored as source in the DB.

**EDIT:**

If you need to pass parameters or Variables into the lookup you should use string interpolation like so:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable
SELECT '@{variables('YourVariable')}' as Variable1,
'@{pipeline().Pipeline} as PipelineName
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, i tried the below SQL in lookup

insert into Table1 (Column1)  Select (''',pipeline().parameters.job_name,''');
select x;

insert into Table1 (Column1)  Select ('@(pipeline().parameters.job_name)');
select x;

Both giving the error 
"Multiple SQL statements in a single API call are not supported; use one API call per statement instead." error.
Any suggestions please..

Comment: You are using two selects, just use one select at the end. For Instance, I just ran this:

TRUNCATE TABLE Log.CVSFormularyFileLog;
TRUNCATE TABLE Log.CVSPharmacyDirectoryFileLog;
Select 'x'

And it ran just fine so just do:

INSERT INTO xxxxxxxxx;
INSERT INTO xxxxxxxxx;
select 'x'

Comment: Please accept as answer/upvote if this meets your needs